# Using functor in pthread_create

Tags: c++, functor

What this code do:

Several commands executed to completion(if(current seconds == some seconds) stop).
CommandProcessor(functor) run this commands. Pointer of this class I try to throw to pthread_create.

The question:

It is possible to use class object as callable?

command.h

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

#include <iostream>
#include "commandprocessor.h"

class CommandProcessor;

using namespace std;

class Command
{
    static CommandProcessor *commandProcessor;
    time_t stopSeconds;

    public:
        Command(int _stopSeconds);
        static void setProcessor(CommandProcessor *_commandProcessor);
        void execute();
};

#endif // COMMAND_H
```

command.cpp

```
#include "command.h"

CommandProcessor* Command::commandProcessor = NULL;

Command::Command(int _stopSeconds)
{
    stopSeconds = _stopSeconds;
}

void Command::setProcessor(CommandProcessor *_commandProcessor)
{
    commandProcessor = _commandProcessor;
}

void Command::execute()
{
    time_t seconds;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    seconds = localtime(&now)->tm_sec;
    cout << seconds << endl;
    if(seconds != stopSeconds)
        commandProcessor->addCommand(this);
}
```

commandprocessor.h

```
#ifndef COMMANDPROCESSOR_H
#define COMMANDPROCESSOR_H

#include <list>
#include "command.h"

using namespace std;

class Command;

class CommandProcessor
{
    list< Command* > commandsList;

    public:
        void addCommand(Command *_command);
        void operator()();
};

#endif // COMMANDPROCESSOR_H
```

commandprocessor.cpp

```
#include "commandprocessor.h"

void CommandProcessor::addCommand(Command *_command)
{
    commandsList.push_back(_command);
}

void CommandProcessor::operator()()
{
    while(commandsList.size() > 0)
    {
        Command *command = commandsList.front();
        commandsList.pop_front();
        command->execute();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "commandprocessor.h"

#define MAX_THREADS 2

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    CommandProcessor *processor = new CommandProcessor();
    Command::setProcessor(processor);
    processor->addCommand(new Command(53));
    processor->addCommand(new Command(24));
    processor->addCommand(new Command(15));

    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, processor(), NULL); // error: 'processor' cannot be used as a function
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_create` takes a `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`. Pass the address of `processor` via the user-supplied argument and have the `start_routine` do a `reinterpret_cast` of the received object to the `CommandProcessor` type, and execute `operator()` on it. Also, why bother with the C thread API anyway? You should be using `std::thread` if possible.

Comment: prefer to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: Please reduce your example to "CommandProcessor* processor;processor();", because that's what the error means that you get. Nothing to do with `pthread_create`. Concerning the question, the answer is "no, not directly", and both other commenters here have a good suggestion what to do instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER : this is the kind of thing that you really shouldn't be doing in C++, as it includes messing around with `void*`. It needs to be used here because of the interaction with the C API. If you can, use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) from C++11 or [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) if you're using an older compiler.**

To answer your question : yes, it is perfectly fine to make a class object as a callable (as a "function") once you implement `operator()` for it. You already did that, but the problem is the extra code needed to implement the interface between C++ and the C API for Pthreads.

The main reason why you're getting the "`processor` cannot be used as a function" error here is because `processor` is a `CommandProcessor*` and, as such, needs a dereference. However, even doing `(*processor)()` wouldn't help you, because `pthread_create` is defined as follows :

```
int pthread_create(phread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

This means that the function to be executed must return `void*` and take a `void*`. The documentation also states that the parameter of `start_routine` has the value of `arg` originally given to the respective call to `pthread_create`.

However, you cannot pass a pointer to `CommandProcessor::operator()()` to `pthread_create` for a much more important reason : it is a member function. All non-`static` class member functions need to be called with an object so that they can refer to `this` inside their body.

The solution to your problem is to make a static function that will match the prototype required by `pthread_create`, and pass the pointer to a `CommandProcessor` as the `arg` of `pthread_create`. Have a look at this :

```
static void* processor_executor(void *arg)
{
    CommandProcessor *processor = static_cast<CommandProcessor*>(arg);
    (*processor)();
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* ... */
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, processor_executor, static_cast<void*>        (processor));
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

This way, `operator()` is executed inside the thread created by `pthread_create`, using the same `CommandProcessor` object as the one in `main()`.

Keep in mind that accessing the same data from within many parallel threads will lead to data races. Use mutexes, semaphores, or condition variables to protect the data from parallel access.

Comment: The reinterpret_cast is used correctly here, with the conversions being the exact opposites. However, there is no need for a reinterpret_cast and it should even be avoided. Instead, just use a static_cast. You could even leave the static_cast to void* out, as that is the equivalent of the implicit conversion.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt : thanks for the comment. My understanding of C++ casts is a bit rusty these days. I was under the (wrong) impression that casts to/from `void*` can only be made via `reinterpret_cast`.